# Algorithm for creating permutation of arrays of integers

Tags: java, algorithm

I am creating an app which will provide mock tests to its user. I have 3 sets of questions from which I need to create other unique sets by using permutations. Each question has a id related to it. So assume that Set 1 has questions with id's from 1 to 50, set 2 has id's from 101 to 150 and set 3 has id's from 201 to 250(P.S. The id's can be anything. Just to make the problem to be simple to understand lets take them to be sequential.). Now id's 1, 101 and 201 are similar type of question, so is 2, 102 and 202 and so on. And no two similar question can some under same set . Please Help.

```
Set 1 - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 .... 50
Set 2 - 101 102 103 104 105 ......150
set 3 - 201 202 203 204 205 ......250
```

What I want to do is create sets with below id's

```
set 4 - 101 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ......50
set 5 - 201 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ......50
set 6 - 1 102 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ......50
set 7 - 1 202 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ......50
set 8 - 1 2 103 4 5 6 7 8 9 ......50
set 9 - 1 2 203 4 5 6 7 8 9 ......50
set 10- 1 2 3 104 5 6 7 8 9 ......50
and so on..
```

I have tried the below code. I was trying for 4 sets with 4 questions.

```
public class GenerateTestSets {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1,i,j=0,k,m,n,temp;
        int[][] test = new int[4][4];
        for(i = 0; i<4;i++){
            for(j=0; j<4; j++){
                test[i][j] = x + j;
            }
            x += 10;
        }

        for(m=0;m<3;m++){
            for(n=0;n<4;n++){
                for(k=0;k<4;k++){
                    for(i = 0; i<4; i++){//Print Logic
                        for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                            System.out.print("\t"+test[i][j]);
                        }//End of J
                        System.out.println("");
                     }//End of i //End of Print Logic
                     System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
                     temp = test[0][0];
                     for(i = 0; i<3;i++){
                         test[i][0] = test[i+1][0];
                     }
                     test[i][0]=temp;
                 }//End of K
                 temp = test[0][m+1];
                 for(i = 0;i<3;i++){
                     test[i][m+1] = test[i+1][m+1];
                 }
                 test[i][m+1]=temp;
             }//End of n
         }//End of m
     }
 }
```

I think the number of total sets that I can create from 3 sets of 50 question is `50*50*50` i.e. 125,000. Thanks in advance. I know this might seem to very simple but I have been stuck on it all day as I need the code to be generic. So you can down vote the question if you want but if you could help, I would really appreciate.

Comment: Can you post the code showing what you have tried so far? And note where you are having problems.

Comment: And any exception stack traces...

Comment: Actually there are some libraries up there that generates permutations. Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I have come up with the logic. Here I have divided the questions into categories and have taken it into array list and then manipulated their positions to get the output. I made a few modification to john's code to come up with mine. Thanks John. You have been of great help.

```
public class GenerateTestSets {
 private final int questionCat;
 private final int setNo;
 private int[] selectedGroups;
 private final int groupDelta;


public GenerateTestSets(final int questionCat, final int setNo, final int groupDelta) {
    this.questionCat = questionCat;
    this.setNo = setNo;
    selectedGroups = new int[questionCat];
    for (int index = 0; index < questionCat; index++) {
        selectedGroups[index] = 1;
    }
    this.groupDelta = groupDelta;
}

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    int [][] input = {{1,11,21},{2,12,22},{3,13,23}};
    int [][] output = new int [100][100];
    final int questionCat = 3, setNo = 3, groupDelta = 10;
    GenerateTestSets p = new GenerateTestSets(questionCat, setNo, groupDelta);
    int selectedGroups[] = p.getNextSelection();
    while (selectedGroups != null) {

        for (int index = 0; index < selectedGroups.length; index++) {
            //System.out.print("\t"+input[index][selectedGroups[index]]);
            output[index][selectedGroups[index]] = input[index][selectedGroups[index]];
            System.out.print("\t"+(selectedGroups[index]+1));
            //System.out.print("\t"+output[index][selectedGroups[index]]);
        }
        p.generateNextSelection();
        selectedGroups = p.getNextSelection();
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private void generateNextSelection() {
    boolean carry = false;
    for (int index = 0; index < questionCat; index++) {
        selectedGroups[index]++;
        carry = selectedGroups[index] > setNo;
        if (carry) {
            selectedGroups[index] = 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (carry) {
        selectedGroups = null;
    }
}

public int[] getNextSelection() {
    int[] cpy;
    if (selectedGroups == null) {
        cpy = null;
    } else {
        cpy = new int[selectedGroups.length];
        for (int index = 0; index < selectedGroups.length; index++) {
            cpy[index] =  ((selectedGroups[index] - 1));
        }
    }
    return cpy;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are making 50 selections, each selection is from a group of 3 items.  The first selection is from group containing [1 101 201], the second selection is from group containing [2 102 202], the third selection is from [3 103 203], and so on up to [50 150 250].

Or, even simpler, you are selecting one item from a group of three, and then adding the column index to the item.  You are selecting from [0 100 200] and adding the index to the number.  So you pick 0 then add 1, and pick 100 and add 2, etc up to 50 columns.

The number of groups is 3 x 3 x 3 up to the number of picks, or 3^N. With N=50, this is about 7.2*10^23.

If there were 2 items selected instead of 50, the complete set of nine selections would be
{  1   2}, {101   2}, {201   2}
{  1 102}, {101 102}, {201 102} 
{  1 202}, {101 202}, {201 202}

We can write the above collection as
11 21 31
12 22 32
13 23 33

where the digit is obtained from (digit-1)*100+column, so 11 gives 1,2; 21 give 101, 2; etc.
Now we have a series that can be generated, where each digit cycles over the number of possible groups, in this case the groups are 0, 100, and 200, or 1, 2, 3 minus 1 * 100.

Starting with an array that contains all the selections (50), with the value initialized to one, so it is an array of all ones.  The next number can be found by incrementing the first index by one.  If the index is greater than the number of groups, ie it is 4, then set the number back to one, and increment the next index.  If the next index is 4, than set it back to one, and increment the next index.  Eventually, you get to all 3s, or the number of groups.  That is the last number.

Here is a code of this approach

```
public class PermutateNItemsSelectedMTimes {
    private final int nItems;
    private final int nGroups;
    private int[] selectedGroups;
    private final int groupDelta;

    public PermutateNItemsSelectedMTimes(final int nItems, final int nGroups, final int groupDelta) {
        this.nItems = nItems;
        this.nGroups = nGroups;
        selectedGroups = new int[nItems];
        for (int index = 0; index < nItems; index++) {
            selectedGroups[index] = 1;
        }
        this.groupDelta = groupDelta;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int nItems = 4, nGroups = 3, groupDelta = 10;
        PermutateNItemsSelectedMTimes p = new PermutateNItemsSelectedMTimes(nItems, nGroups, groupDelta);
        int selectedGroups[] = p.getNextSelection();
        while (selectedGroups != null) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            for (int index = 0; index < selectedGroups.length; index++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%2d", selectedGroups[index]));
                if (index < (selectedGroups.length - 1)) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("{" + sb.toString() + "}");
            p.generateNextSelection();
            selectedGroups = p.getNextSelection();
        }
    }

    private void generateNextSelection() {
        boolean carry = false;
        for (int index = 0; index < nItems; index++) {
            selectedGroups[index]++;
            carry = selectedGroups[index] > nGroups;
            if (carry) {
                selectedGroups[index] = 1;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (carry) {
            selectedGroups = null;
        }
    }

    public int[] getNextSelection() {
        int[] cpy;
        if (selectedGroups == null) {
            cpy = null;
        } else {
            cpy = new int[selectedGroups.length];
            for (int index = 0; index < selectedGroups.length; index++) {
                cpy[index] = index + 1 + ((selectedGroups[index] - 1) * groupDelta);
            }
        }
        return cpy;
    }
}
```